# Change username to nickname in comment section

Tags: comments

Is it possible to change the username to nickname in the comments section?

Here's the code I currently use to show the user's username in comment section:

```
    <?php
    /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: date and time */
        printf( '%1$s  %2$s ',
            sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', get_comment_author_link() ),

            sprintf( '',
                esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                sprintf( '%1$s ، %2$s', get_comment_date("d M Y"), get_comment_time() )
                ));
            ?>
```

I tried using below code instead of the above code to show the nickname:

```
<?php
    $commenter_id = $comment->user_id;
    $commenter_name =  get_usermeta($commenter_id,'nickname');?>
<?php echo $commenter_name; ?>
```

But the problem is after posting a comment by a guest user, it doesn't show the name he added before posting comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it won't show any name for guest comments because they are not registered users of your website so they don't have any `nickname` associated.

What you can do in this situation, is add a check before printing the nickname, if comment was made by a user or a guest. And act accordingly.

So this is the code you want to use instead.

```
if ( $comment->user_id != '0' ) {
    echo '<span class="some-class">' . get_user_meta( $comment->user_id, 'nickname', true ) . '</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class="other-class">' . get_comment_author_link() . '</span>';
}
```

This checks if commenter `user_id` is `0` (for guests) then it will show guest name with link url (default) and if it is a user then it will print user's nickname.

Comment: Thank you so so much, Robert. But how can I add a class to second or forth line for styling?

Comment: @KevinArmstrong I have updated code and added span classes for each. Please check.